# Error http uploading images on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, imagick

I'm working with Imagick and I don't know what happens because when I upload an file "png" or "jpg" It returns:

> Error HTTP

but when I upload an file "jpge" it works perfectly.

This is the code on functions.php:

```
  add_filter( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'generate_watermarked_image' );

function watermark_image( $filename, $upload_dir ) {

  $original_image_path = trailingslashit( $upload_dir['path'] ) . $filename;

  $image_resource = new Imagick( $original_image_path );
  $watermark_resource = new Imagick( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/images/logo.png' );
  $image_resource->compositeImage( $watermark_resource, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0 );

  return save_watermarked_image( $image_resource, $original_image_path );

}

function save_watermarked_image( $image_resource, $original_image_path ) {

  $image_data = pathinfo( $original_image_path );

  $new_filename = $image_data['filename'] . '-watermarked.' . $image_data['extension'];

  $watermarked_image_path = str_replace($image_data['basename'], $new_filename, $original_image_path);

  if ( ! $image_resource->writeImage( $watermarked_image_path ) )
    return $image_data['basename'];

  unlink( $original_image_path ); // Because that file isn't referred to anymore

  return $new_filename;

}
```

I'm sorry for my english.

Comment: What **exactly** is the error message, in full?

Comment: Where can i check that error on functions.php?

Comment: Have you checked the [error log](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) yet?

Comment: Error log shows none.

Comment: On media library you can't see the images: http://prntscr.com/kckqbo